# how can i resolve an object required error

Tags: vba, excel

i'm working on a macro that helps me to copy data from one worksheet to another in Excel with on  conditions. I tried the following code but i got an object required error

Any help is appreciated

```
Sub copier()
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, src As Range, dest As Range, i As Integer

   Set ws1 = Worksheets("Workload - Charge de travail")
   Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

   For i = 2 To ws1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row        

       Set src = ws1.Range("A" & i & ":AL" & i + 50)
       Set dest = ws2.Range("A" & i & ":AL" & i + 50)

        If Source.Cells(i, 31).Value = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" Then

          '(i,31) this is  for my drop down list's condition


          src.Copy Destination:=dest
          dest.Value = dest.Value
       End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Source`?  Should it be `src`?

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Answer (score 1):

Salut, veuyer verifier que "Source", should not be the sheet "src".

I'm also guessing you're trying to copy just one row at a time,

- `Range("A" & i & ":AL" & i) which is "A2:AL2" rather than`
- `Range("A" & i & ":AL" & i + 50)  is "A2:AL52"`

Also check that cells(y,31) is intended to be "AE", which is before AL (column 38).

Answer (score 0):

You use `Source` instead of `src`

```
 If Source.Cells(i, 31).Value = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété...
```

Comment: thanks i tried it works but it doesn't respect the condition it copies all the lines , i need only for those who has  ("Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite")

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems, `Source` should not be `src` it should be `ws1`.  `src.cells(i ...)` will go to the i row after the row src is already referencing.  If i is 50 then it will get the result from row 100.

Also I belive you only want one row copied at a time instead of 50 rows.

```
 Sub copier()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, src As Range, dest As Range, i As Integer

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Workload - Charge de travail")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 2 To ws1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

        Set src = ws1.Range("A" & i & ":AL" & i)
        Set dest = ws2.Range("A" & i & ":AL" & i)

         If ws1.Cells(i, 31).value = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" Then

           '(i,31) this is  for my drop down list's condition


           src.Copy Destination:=dest
           'dest.value = dest.value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```